# My PWA is not showing 'Add To Homescreen' Banner in mobile Chrome (Android)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

My PWA Add To Homescreen  banner works perfectly in desktop but it is not working in android mobile

Here is my manifest.json file

```js
{
  "short_name": "SK",
  "name": "SK App",
  "description": "Make Your Shop Online.",
  "icons" : [
  {
      "src" : "admin_shop_img/ai.png",
      "type" : "image/png",
      "sizes" : "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src" : "admin_shop_img/ai.png",
    "type" : "image/png",
    "sizes" : "512x512"
  }
  ],
  "start_url": "/admin_area/details2.php?shop_id=6",
  "background_color" : "#3367D6" ,
  "display": "standalone" ,
  "theme_color" : "#3367D6"

}
```

And Here is my sw.js

```js
    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
  self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
      console.log('service worker has been installed');
  });

  self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    console.log(e.request.url);
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then((response) => response || fetch(e.request)),
    );
  });
```

index.js

```js
 // Register service worker to control making site work offline

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('sw.js')
    .then(() => { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
}

// Code to handle install prompt on desktop

let deferredPrompt;
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
addBtn.style.display = 'none';

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
  addBtn.style.display = 'block';

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    addBtn.style.display = 'none';
    // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
  });
});
 







     <button class="add-button" style="">Add To Home Screen</button>
```

Kindly Help me with this

I don't understand that what problem is coming. I am new to PWA
When I am opening this in desktop the a2hs banner is showing and working properly but it is not showing in mobile devices .